# Camera api example?

Tags: android, camera

I want to develop a camera demo app using the following web page example.
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

After taking a photo, I want to display the captured image in the main activity. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use another example. I can't get this one to work. Judging by the other Camera questions in SO, I think lots of people have the same problem. But before you give up on Marakana's example completely, try moving the  elements OUTSIDE the  element. And include the  Marko forgot.

By doing that, I got past the RuntimeException, and now get a completely different error, one I think is specific to my phone: it is trying to create a Preview with an 'invalid preview size' of 480x604. But Marko's code sets the size from the size of the preview surface created,, so the phone itself is defaulting to an invalid size for the Preview surface.